# In-site end-form links don't trigger linked question

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, linked-questions

If I want to link to question post #10 on the current site, I can link in either of these two ways:

`[Link text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10)`

`[Link text](/q/10)`

The problem is, the latter kind aren't being picked up in the "linked questions" section. Let's fix that.

To prove it, [here's a short-form link to question 1234](/q/1234). (Please don't post other links between that question and this one.)

Comment: Funny enough apparently it's catching the link to Q 10 from the code section.